# Why my extension does not have an "inspect views"?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I made a simple MV3 extension, but I have bugs concerning the communication between content script and background script.

I would like to debug my background script, but can't!
[image: No "inspect views"...]

I will begin with my manifest, feel free to ask for more.

```
{
    "name": "poc-ext-es",
    "description": "Trying to execute arbitrary string in the page context",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background.service_worker": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [ { "resources": ["inpage.js"], "matches": ["<all_urls>"] } ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
          "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
          "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
          "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
          "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
   },

Comment: Many thanks! If you post an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Do not mention it.

Comment: This looks like a typo-tier problem or maybe you've used an incorrect tutorial. In case this mistake was prompted by the official documentation it'd be right to report the problem in [their repository](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/issues).

Comment: Oh, I guess it's the confusing error message that Chrome shows about `background.service_worker` key, in which case it should be reported to https://crbug.com.

Comment: @wOxxOm There was NO confusing error message, at all.

Comment: So where did you get `background.service_worker` from?

Comment: @wOxxOm I made lot of tests with several sample extensions, with MV2 and MV3. I haven't the slightest idea on how I ended up with background.service_worker in my manifest. What I am sure of is I had NO error messages and NO "inspect views" link